# Understanding ffmpeg recording input types from devices

Tags: ffmpeg, microphone, alsa, pulse-audio

Using `pactl`, I get the following sinks:

```
pactl list sinks short
# 0       alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
```

Since there's but one sink, I'd expect it to be the default sink, so that the following commands would have the same bahaviour:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i 0 -c:a flac "$HOME/audio.flac"
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -c:a flac "$HOME/audio.flac"
```

However, the first copies audio *as is* from played media (is it recording from a source?), while the latter records the audio captured from the speakers with the built-in microphone.

To top it off, while looking more like the first option, the following command using *alsa* behaves like the second option (records from the built-in microphone):

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -c:a flac "$HOME/audio.flac"
```

My goal is to understand how to differentiate these inputs and when to use alsa or pulse in order to record both played media audio and ANY other sink (i.e built-in or external microphones) listed by pactl.

I understand that device-specific configuration will most likely be required and wish for guidelines, not a one-for-all solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `pactl list sinks short` when you should really be doing `pactl list sources short`.

When doing `ffmpeg -f pulse -i` you're specifying a **source**, not a sink.

The first (`0`) source of pulse on my system is `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor` which is the monitor of your audio output (so it records exactly what is being played). The second (`1`) source on my system is the built-in laptop microphone.

Try these two commands:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i 1 -c:a flac "$HOME/audio.flac"
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -c:a flac "$HOME/audio.flac"
```

Should be the same. (Double check with `pactl list sources short` though).

Comment: And I'm guessing your other `-f alsa` command behaves like you expect because you specified `hw:0` as the input, `hw` being `hardware` so the first (`0`) being your microphone, as the `monitor` would be software. (I'm guessing)